# what is the best way to determine is a double is not zero

Tags: c#, .net

Any suggestion on determining a double is not zero?

Answer (score 6):

You have to set an *epsilon* that is compatible with the problem you are solving. Then, you could use something like

```
bool DoubleEquals(double value1, double value2)
{
    return Math.Abs(value1 - value2) < epsilon;
}
```

**EDIT**
Since you asked a way to determine if a double is not zero, you could use this function by writing:

```
if (!DoubleEquals(value, 0)) { /* do your not zero things */ }
```

I felt this method was better because it's more general purpose.

Answer (score 3):

Hi depends on what sort of calculations you are doing. Some times you get a very small number which is close to 0 but not quite

I usually do

```
if (Math.Abs(MyNumber) < 1e-10)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: opps. i think 1e-10 is my C++ talking. C# would be Math.Pow(1,-10) as Gunner said

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( Math.Abs(doubleNumber) > Math.Pow(1,-9) ) //doubleNumber not zero.
```

Answer (score 0):

This much is enough to check the double is zero or not

```
        double d = 0.00000005;
        bool l =  d.Equals(0);
```